# Saving files on local machine by Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

My chrome app needs to save a file with human-readable or standard format such as `SQLite` (It should be readable outside Chrome).

Is there any API suitable for this purpose?

Some files with `.localstorage` extension (`SQLite` format) are in `Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage` folder. Is it possible to create such files by the app?

**Edited:** The app should not ask user for extra permission.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

[`chrome.fileSystem` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) is what you need.

You will need to ask the user at least once where to save the file, but then you can retain the entry to write again to the same file/folder.

There is no way around asking the user to "escape the sandbox".

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [Quota Management API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Quota-Management-API-Fast-Facts). This is per-origin storage, and you request specific amounts of quota.

It sounds like you also want your users to open the files directly? There's an [HTML5 filesystem explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-filesystem-explorer/nhnjmpbdkieehidddbaeajffijockaea) Chrome app that you can use. It'll show you the files, and you can figure things out from their URLs (e.g. I'm currently using `filesystem:http://localhost:8000/temporary/bar` for a local experiment).

Or are you looking for something more user friendly? I think you have to use file save in that case, the same way Google Drive does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that the app should not ask user for extra permission. I just need to save some text files so that the user of the app can open them outside the browser. The location of the files is not important. Btw, in Developer Tools, it is possible to read persistent files in html5fs created by NaCl, but, unfortunately, it is not possible to save files (manual copy-paste is inefficient for huge files).

Comment: @KaBa I see. The only other thing I can think of is that maybe Service Worker's caching facilities will do what you want? It's still pretty early and I think right now it's marked as temporary storage and is unlimited, but may change in the future. I'm also not sure how to access the files externally, that may be an upcoming feature.